# Google Cloud Endpoints API with Flask

Tags: python, google-app-engine, flask, sqlalchemy, google-cloud-endpoints

Folks:
I am considering building out the server side of my application based on Flask and SqlAlchemy. I am considering hosting these on Google cloud platform. I am intrigued by the promise of Google Endpoints API, but put off by the additional code I will have to write on top of the functions I'll have to write anyway for my REST services.

Has anyone used the combination of Flask on Google App Engine with Google Endpoints? Any suggestions/pointers?

Thanks.

-Raj

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://github.com/Eforcers/gae-flask-todo) example.

Comment: Thanks @doru. How does Endpoints interact with a REST endpoint you might code up in, say Flask?

Answer (score 0):

The phrase "Google Cloud Endpoints" somewhat means two things:

1. It's a *software library* (Python package) which lets you write APIs and run them anywhere Python apps can run
2. It's a Google Cloud service too, which allows you to

   1. See your logs in a different location than, say, your other GAE Services (ie UI)
   2. View API usage stats with more detail at https://console.cloud.google.com/endpoints/portal

When thinking of Cloud Endpoints as a *software library*, is akin to writing a an API with, say, Flask-RESTful, but ropes you into one of two design decisions:

1. OpenAPI
2. Google Remote RPC

Once you write your API using `endpoints` Python package, you then have additional choices on how to deploy it.  You *could* deploy it as its own GAE Service or to the Cloud Endpoints *service* mentioned above.  Deploying it there is basically using GAE on your behalf to run your API (written using the `endpoints` Python package).

In my opinion, Cloud Endpoints isn't ready for prime time yet unless you have a pretty simple API (ie just doing CRUD operations on Datastore Entities).  The reasons I say this because

1. Cloud Endpoints is limited to Python 2.7 which is sunsetting this year
2. Cloud Endpoints has conflicting requirements with other Google API Python packages (ie  text-to-speech), which means your API can't do anything very interesting.
3. As you noted, the syntax for `endpoints` is a bit verbose, BUT, this is because Cloud Endpoints not only serves an API for you, but also an OpenAPI/Swagger UI for other developers to use to explore your API.  It also handles auth etc.  When considering the work required to use, say, [`flask-restful-swagger-2.0`](https://pypi.org/project/flask-restful-swagger-2/) to decorate all your classes and methods, the `endpoints` code overhead is pretty reasonable I think.

I've spent half a week trying to write an app similar in architecture to yours: Flask UI on GAE with Cloud Endpoints hosting my API.  In the end, due to items 1 & 2 above, I decided to abandon it and use Flask for my API too as a separate GAE Service: This will let logs be easily filtered and give me some decent graphs to get a feel for usage, latencies, etc.